# C++ variable scope

Tags: c++, c++11, scope

I have C++ code different output compared to what I expected, I hope to understand how it's executed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int x = 8;

class A {
public:
    A() { 
        int x = 5 ;
    }

    void print (int x = 4) { 
         std::cout << "the scope variable"<< ::x << "passed variable" << x;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.print(7);
}
```

I expected to be 5 and 7 but the result is  8  and 7

Comment: What, **exactly**, is unexpected for you, and why?

Comment: What are you expecting? What is the question?

Comment: `::x` means `x` from the global namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expected the output 5 and 7 then the constructor has to deal with the global variable instead of the local variable.

That is instead of

```
A(){int x = 5 ;}
```

you should write either

```
A(){ x = 5 ;}
```

or

```
A(){ ::x = 5 ;}
```

Take into account that it would be better to declare the variable `x` as a static data member of the class `A`.

For example

```
class A {
    public :
    //...
    private:
        static int x;  
    };

//...

int A::x = 0;
```

In this case only objects of the class could access the variable.

Comment: could you please illustrate why the constructor failed to define x and the scope ::x get it's value from the global variable, this code is so confusing for me

Comment: @ahmedosama I do not understand what you are asking. In your constructor there is used a local variable that is destroyed at once after exiting the constructor. That is the local variable will not be alive after exiting the constructor. How are you going to access what does not exists?

Comment: so the variable x inside the constructor has no exist after the execution of the constructor.  this is the part i was confused about why x is defined inside constructor by 5 and not appearing in the output

Comment: @ahmedosama Because it does not exists outside the constructor and it exists only during execution of the constructor. Nothing knows about its existence inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor body of `A` is a no-op and is therefore a red herring. (You are declaring an `int` in local scope.)

The global variable `x` is *always* 8.

That is *shadowed* by the parameter name passed to `print`.

It would have been less uninteresting had the constructor body been `x = 5;`, then indeed the result would have been 5 and 7.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by no-op ?

Comment: It means no-operation, i.e. has absolutely no effect and a good optimising compiler will remove it.

Comment: what is the reason for that? , constructor define a local variable in the class and ::x is related to the class what is the reason for the conflict?

Comment: There's no conflict. *Shadowing* is well-defined by the standard.